# Can I get a list of all source files from a target name in gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu

`make help` gives me a list of target names, can I get a list of all source files needed to build one of these targets?

Comment: Are you sure that gnu make does that? I know that a Makefile generated by cmake has this target. Are you using cmake?

Comment: Yes, cmake is used to generate the make files. Maybe I should rephrase my question to be: Can I get a list of all source files from a target name in cmake? But I can't even get a list of all targets in cmake, that's why I didn't ask it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can by passing `-p` option to make. It outputs all rules and dependencies. But you will have to build a graph of dependencies from that output yourself.

Comment: I cannot see the `.cpp` files in the output of make -pn, maybe they're hidden behind variables? Also, how do I pass the target name to make?

Comment: @bug this is what I meant by building the graph: you can find which `.o` are linked into an `.exe`, but then you need to find which `.cpp` are compiled into those `.o` files.

Comment: How can you get the list of `.cpp` files from the list of `.o` files?

Comment: @bug `.cpp` files are dependencies of `.o` files in `make -p` output.

Answer (score 0):

U may not be able to get something which u might not have mentioned in the rules of makefile.
However if I understood correctly, i.e. you want to know/list what are the files which has been mentioned as dependent for a given target.
Then this would be of help to you.
make target VERBOSE=1 
This would list the rules along with the target/include and all dependencies